# How do I display CSS along with HTML in a webbrower control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

So I looked around on MSDN trying to find how to display html in a webbrowser control.
Which turned out to be quite easy using `NavigateToString` 
But how do I display the CSS with it? This is what I have so far.

```
wbMain.NavigateToString("  <table style=\"width:100%\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <th>Firstname</th>\r\n    <th>Lastname</th>\r\n    <th>Age</th>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Jill</td>\r\n    <td>Smith</td>\r\n    <td>50</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Eve</td>\r\n    <td>Jackson</td>\r\n    <td>94</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</table> ");
```

wbMain is the WebBrowser control

Answer (score 0):

```
display the CSS
```

I don't get what you mean. Just make a webpage in notepad, including style and all the usual tags, then paste that junk into the NavigateToString method.

btw, this is a html question, nothing to do with .net